# Error Validating in xcode- Invalid Bundle Structure

Tags: xcode6

I'm trying to validate my project in xcode to prep it for upload to the store and I've run into this error:

"iTunes Store operation failed.
Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file [bundleidentifier]/GooglePlus.framework/GooglePlus' is not permitted. Your app can't contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles...etc"

and

"iTunes Store operation failed.
Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file [bundleidentifier]/gpg.framework/Versions/A/gpg' is not permitted. Your app can't contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles...etc"

Anyone have any idea how to solve it? Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove GooglePlus.bundle from your project.